# Prime numbers on a non-standard model

Tags: logic, arithmetic, nonstandard-models

I can't imagine how this is possible:

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a nonstandard model of arithmetic. Show that:

- There is an element $a\in M$ such that for all prime numbers $p$, we have that $\mathcal{M} \vDash S^p0|a$.
- There is an element $a\in M$, $a>1$ such that for no prime number $p$, we have that $\mathcal{M} \vDash S^p0|a$.

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: The question is written in a strange way. Normally, if we are talking about a model $M$, and we say "prime number", we would mean a prime number from the point of view of $M$. But the question means a *standard* prime number.  So any *nonstandard* prime $q$ would answer part 2, and then $q!$ would answer part 1. Note that $S^n0$ is just the standard term denoting the number $n$ within $M$.

Comment: I think the basic idea will be: if $n$ is a nonstandard element, then the factorial $n!$ is divisible by everything between $1$ and $n$, in particular by every standard prime.  Similarly, $n!+1$ is divisible by nothing between $2$ and $n$, so divisible by no standard prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi$ be  the sentence that says that for every $x\gt 0$ there is a $y\gt 0$ such that $t$ divides $y$ for every $t$ in the interval $0\lt t\le x$.

This sentence is not difficult to write down in the usual language of first-order arithmetic, and is true in the natural numbers.

Now let $M$ be a non-standard model of "true arithmetic," and let $m\in M$ be larger than every standard integer. Then since $\varphi$ is true in $M$, there is an $a$ such that $t$ divides $a$ for every $t$ in the interval $0\lt t\le m$. In particular, every standard prime divides $a$. (Since $\varphi$ is a theorem of first-order Peano arithmetic, the same argument works for models of that theory.)

For the second part, instead of the $a$ of the previous argument, use $a+1$.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, I undertand the first, but I don't undertand the second part. Could you give me a hint for that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is unfortunate that the second question says there is an $a$ such that $\dots$. Replace it by there is a $b$ such that $\dots$. Let $a$ be a number that satisfies the condition of the first part.. Let $b=a+1$. Any standard prime $p$ divides $a$. So $p$ cannot divide $b$, else it would divide $1$.    (So I used the result of the first part. There are other ways, for example by using the fact that there is a true sentence $\psi$ that says that for every $x$ there is a number $\gt x$ which is not divisible by any number between $2$ and $x$.)

Comment: Thanks, I finally understand it!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Your notation for the first claim suggest you mean "every prime" to be every standard prime.  Then it can happen, since there are numbers $a$ in the model greater than all standard numbers and thus greater than all standard primes, and every such number has a factorial $a!$.  No number in any model is divisible by every prime in the model, since PA proves every number has some prime greater than it.

Also, no model has a number not divisible by any prime in the model; but every nonstandard model has numbers not divisible by any standard prime, since you can take the number $a$ above and take any prime greater than that.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't imagine how this is possible

The point of this kind of problem is that functions like $N!$ for the first problem and $N!+1$ for the second extend to the whole nonstandard model, and share the same first-order properties (such as being divisible or not by all the primes up to $N$) but their values at infinite $N$ have interesting properties when viewed externally.

Comment: You mean nonstandard numbers can actually have "interesting" properties?

Comment: It's interesting if you already accept a division into standard/nonstandard as interesting and want to develop that way of thinking.   As with any other flavor of mathematics some statements are more striking than others, though in this case the striking-ness comes from suppressing some words like "standard" in the theorem statement.

Comment: OK, so yours was a conditional answer :-)

Comment: I know you were joking somewhat, but a parallel would be Cantor set theory.  The vocabulary of things being "infinite" or "uncountable", yet having some provable properties, is very striking when one learns it the first time.  From a later-learned point of view, we don't really want set-theoretic equivalence, but some more structured parametrization, so the magic may dissipate for some people, while others will still find it magical enough to keep exploring.

Comment: As you know a computer is merely a Turing machine so all the fancy high-level languages are just salad dressing so to speak, and their magic may dissipate for some people.  Does that mean I should program a Turing machine in order to access by bank account through www?

Comment: If somebody demonstrates a tradeoff-free version of nonstandard analysis, people will "vote with their feet" by switching formalisms.   This demonstration is assumed to have taken place, as some kind of minor detail, when telling the story in terms of stone-age technology and bank accounts.

Comment: That's a nice challenge.  Could you clarify what you mean by a trade-off free version exactly? This sounds like it could make a nice *question* if handled calmly.

Comment: I think Paul Garrett's answer to one of your (I think it was yours) questions already discussed the issue of tradeoffs.  Tradeoff-free has the usual meaning, substantial gain with little or no loss.

Comment: By "loss" do you mean the necessity to develop the hyperreal framework?

Comment: I mean the tradeoff of the good and the bad that come with that part of NSA going beyond simple (from today's viewpoint) standard locutions for infinite and infinitesimal objects.

Comment: Well zyx I am honestly trying to understand your comment but I am still not sure what exactly you mean by the "bad" here.  I am perfectly willing to envision the possibility of bad things but what are *you* referring to specifically?

Comment: Examples we discussed under some of your posts are that for elementary/concrete 18th century type of applications, a NSA argument can generally be shortened to a stronger standard argument; and that there are easier standard frameworks for having infinitesimals as actual objects, that suffice for those applications.  So NSA is actually somewhat of a negative in relation to its main selling point, and the question is whether its strengths in less elementary areas (typically signalled by moderate or heavy use of AC) compensate for that.

Comment: This in addition to any conceptual, syntactic or foundational complexities of the Robinson model theoretic approach.

Comment: Well zyx if using AC is posited as absolute evil then it is going to be very difficult to argue for a positive trade-off :-)

Comment: I'm not postulating that.  NSA simply tends to appear more in such applications.  It correlates with AC but the applications can be evaluated on their own.

Comment: Would you be willing to post this as a *question*? I certainly find it interesting.

Comment: I'm busy for the next 6 weeks but maybe we can come back to it later.  Or by email some time.

Comment: I tried counting weeks but ran out of fingers.